# Any way to have text-shadow that doesn't show through behind text?

Tags: opacity, alpha, css

I want to have text that has a shadow/glow, but the problem is that the text itself is slightly transparent and the shadow shows through behind it, colouring the text.

```
color: rgba(226,229,226,0.88);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: .5px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #9c9c9c;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 29px #333;
```

Is there any CSS method that acheive this? box-shadow doesn't seem to affect the colouration of a slightly transparent item casting a shadow, so this behaviour is inconsistent (especially when you want text to have the same appearance as a box).

Here is a jsfiddle to explain what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/KzxrK/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the exact same text, in your background color and same size and shape, behind your text.

Using something like this and respective CSS:

```
<h1>█</h1><h1 class="c1">█</h1>
```

EDIT: As shown here with your edited jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KzxrK/2/

Comment: the problem with this is there is content behind the transparent item that should partially show through... so long as the shadow is there it will interfere with that.

Comment: Oh I see... I'll try to find a solution for your problem, but I think I've never seen anything like that mate :(